# Jasmine - mock spyOn.and.callFake http success error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

in my controller I have a call to an http service.  This is my controller:

```
myApp.controller('MyController', function MyController($scope, myData) {
  myData.getItemsByPage(1, 10)
    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.items = data.items;
    })
    .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        var test = 1;
    });
});
```

This is the Jasmine test:

```
it('it should return results', function () {
  var results = {
    "items": [
        {"Title": "Star Wars1","Year": "1977"},
        {"Title": "Star Wars2","Year": "1980"},
        {"Title": "Star Wars3","Year": "1983"}]
  };

  spyOn(myData, 'getItemsByPage').and.callFake(function (message, success, fail) {
        return {
            success: function (successCallback) {
                var status = {};
                var headers = function() {
                    return {
                        'x-pagination': '{"totalCount": 3}'
                    }
                };
                var config = {};

                successCallback(results, status, headers, config);
            },
            error: function (fail) {
                var x = 1;
            }
        }
    });
    $rootScope.$apply();
    $controller('MyController', { $scope: $scope });
});
```

I am getting the exception
"TypeError: Unable to get property 'error' of undefined or null reference"

Comment: I'm getting same error. Don't know how to resolve..???

Answer (score 1):

for some reason you have to return an error object after calling the success method.

```
spyOn(myData, 'getItemsByPage').and.callFake(function (message, success, fail) 
{
    return {
        success: function (successCallback) {
            var status = {};
            var headers = function() {
                return {
                    'x-pagination': '{"totalCount": 3}'
                }
            };
            var config = {};

            successCallback(results, status, headers, config);

            return {
                error: function (errorCallback) {
                    var x = 1;
                }
           }
        },
        error: function (fail) {
            var x = 1;
        }
    }
});
```